# Using re module in python to extract data between two brackets

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing

this is a test string 
"transparent url(http://www.google.com/chart?chs=630x100&cht=bvs&chxt=x&chxl=0:%7C1840%7C1860%7C1880%7C1900%7C1920%7C1940%7C1960%7C1980%7C2000%7C&chxr=0,0,100&chxs=0,676767,11.3000002,0,tl,676767,676767&chd=e:D9AACPFjGWAAGDLfCeFgBvHLLSCZGED5GOKwDKCxJmF2FwFfERFwEZGcEJHlENJDJ9I0HQDjE-MAK2J9NMI9IAFtNaIOKtGoG2IYKBFvLEJmMLHdIFHXG.IPHrK2I9ULROI8SfHRFTeCIrQPOwXgPHVxQkbCbhg8iDwIvKkety..AAAAAAAA&chbh=7,0,0&chg=11.11,0,5,6&chxp=0,0.0,11.1,22.2,33.3,44.4,55.6,66.7,77.8,88.9&chco=3366cc,bbcced&chm=R,bbbbbb,0,0.9954,1.0%7Ch,bbbbbb,0,1.0,1.0,1&chxs=0,000000,11,-1&hl=en)"

i want to extract all the data in between the two brackets - the one after url in first line and the closing bracket at the end- using re module of python

Comment: i hd tried this re.search("url\\(.\\)",string) and other variants of this

Comment: You were close then `re.search(r'\((.*)\)',string).group(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ python
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Jun 13 2011, 22:03:32) 
[GCC 4.6.1 20110608 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('\(([^)]*)\)').search("transparent url(http://www.google.com/chart?chs=630x100&cht=bvs&chxt=x&chxl=0:%7C1840%7C1860%7C1880%7C1900%7C1920%7C1940%7C1960%7C1980%7C2000%7C&chxr=0,0,100&chxs=0,676767,11.3000002,0,tl,676767,676767&chd=e:D9AACPFjGWAAGDLfCeFgBvHLLSCZGED5GOKwDKCxJmF2FwFfERFwEZGcEJHlENJDJ9I0HQDjE-MAK2J9NMI9IAFtNaIOKtGoG2IYKBFvLEJmMLHdIFHXG.IPHrK2I9ULROI8SfHRFTeCIrQPOwXgPHVxQkbCbhg8iDwIvKkety..AAAAAAAA&chbh=7,0,0&chg=11.11,0,5,6&chxp=0,0.0,11.1,22.2,33.3,44.4,55.6,66.7,77.8,88.9&chco=3366cc,bbcced&chm=R,bbbbbb,0,0.9954,1.0%7Ch,bbbbbb,0,1.0,1.0,1&chxs=0,000000,11,-1&hl=en)").groups()[0]
'http://www.google.com/chart?chs=630x100&cht=bvs&chxt=x&chxl=0:%7C1840%7C1860%7C1880%7C1900%7C1920%7C1940%7C1960%7C1980%7C2000%7C&chxr=0,0,100&chxs=0,676767,11.3000002,0,tl,676767,676767&chd=e:D9AACPFjGWAAGDLfCeFgBvHLLSCZGED5GOKwDKCxJmF2FwFfERFwEZGcEJHlENJDJ9I0HQDjE-MAK2J9NMI9IAFtNaIOKtGoG2IYKBFvLEJmMLHdIFHXG.IPHrK2I9ULROI8SfHRFTeCIrQPOwXgPHVxQkbCbhg8iDwIvKkety..AAAAAAAA&chbh=7,0,0&chg=11.11,0,5,6&chxp=0,0.0,11.1,22.2,33.3,44.4,55.6,66.7,77.8,88.9&chco=3366cc,bbcced&chm=R,bbbbbb,0,0.9954,1.0%7Ch,bbbbbb,0,1.0,1.0,1&chxs=0,000000,11,-1&hl=en'
```